# GeoPHP geosInstalled returns false

Tags: php, geos, geophp

I have installed OSGeo4W on my 64-bit windows. I am trying to use `GEOS` functions in GeoPHP, but when I call `geoPHP::geosInstalled`, it returns me `false`. This is how I included the libraries:

```
<?php
echo "Going to load libraries...\n";
include_once("C:\\Users\\ZiZi\\Desktop\\GEOPHP\\Libs\\geoPHP-master\\geoPHP.inc");
var_dump(geoPHP::geosInstalled());
```

The output is:

```
bool(false)
```

I have installed `oSGeo4W` which is said [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos) to be containing `GEOS`. It is installed in `C:\OSGeo4W64` and I have put `C:\OSGeo4W64` and `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin` into my `path` environment variable and rebooted the system once. What did I miss?

Comment: Are you sure you can use backslashes in the path? I recall it's at least adviced to use forward slashes

Comment: @Andreas It works for everything else; it should work for this one too.

Answer (score 0):

The [GeoPHP](https://geophp.net/geos.html) website says:

> Installation
>
> To install GEOS with it's PHP extension, you need to compile it from source. This may sound scary, but it's really quite easy! Various instructions on installing GEOS (with the requisite PHP extension) can be found here:
>
> ```
> http://wygoda.net/blog/testing-geos-33-php-bindings (Best Instructions)
> http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/wiki/BuildingOnUnixWithAutotools
> http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/wiki/BuildingOnUnixWithCMake
> ```
>
> Ubuntu: See Howto install libgeos with PHP5 bindings on Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 LTS
>
> MAMP users: See GEOS Installation on OSX with MAMP for special requirements.
>
> CentOS 6 users: See GEOS Installation on CentOS6 for special instructions.

So, it's necessary to compile the GEOS with GeoPHP extension before to use their class, probably will be necessary dedicate some time to do this on Windows OS.

I hope it helps and good luck!